# deserialization XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

can somebody help with this problem. I have created class for deserialization data from XML. But when I programme compile VS shows me this exception InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document(2,2) so I guess that I defined attribute Month in class Store. I tried to type into int and without successfull please help me... Here is the code of problem:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Store>
 <StoreS Month="2">
    <Amount>159</Amount>
    <Mod_date> 20.3.2014 18:19:18</Mod_date>
  </StoreS>
  <StoreS Month="2">
    <Amount>270</Amount>
    <Mod_date> 20.3.2014 18:19:40</Mod_date>
  </StoreS>
  </Store>
```

The class into which I wanna to deserialize data is written this way:

```
 [XmlRoot("Store"),XmlType("Store")]
 public class Store 
 {
     [XmlElement("StoreS")]
     public List<RecordStore> StoreS = new List<RecordStore>();
     [XmlAttribute("Month")]
     public string Month { get; set; }

  }

public class RecordStore
{

    [XmlElement("Amount")]
    public int amount{get;set;}

    [XmlElement("Mod_date")]
    public DateTime mod_date { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: An "Error in XML document (2,2)" is usually that there's something weird at this character position in the text document. This error occurs before any assignment to objects begins, so I doubt that this has to do with data types in your classes, but rather the content of the XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `xml` has bad datetime format, it should be like `2014-03-21T00:00:00`, for example

Answer (score 0):

as you serialize in the same way you can de-serialize the object

```
    public void Serialize<T>(T details)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Xml.xml"))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, details);
        }
    }

    public void Deserialize<T>(out T obj)
    {            
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader("Xml.xml"))
        {
            obj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```